# INSERT INTO dynamic columns from JSON

Tags: php, sql, json, pdo

This is how I insert static data into my database table:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

    $campaign = (isset($_POST['campaign'])) ? $_POST['campaign'] : null;
    $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['surname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date_of_birth = (isset($_POST['day']) && is_numeric($_POST['day']) && isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] != 'Monat' && isset($_POST['year']) && is_numeric($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['day'] . '.' . $_POST['month'] . '.' . $_POST['year'] : '';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $created_on = time();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO t_weltwoche_address_infos2018_test (salutation, firstname, lastname, address, loctation, country, phone, email, date_of_birth, remoteAddress, createdon) VALUES (:salutation, :firstname, :lastname, :address, :loctation, :country, :phone, :email, :date_of_birth, :remoteAddress, :createdon)");

    $stmt -> bindParam(':salutation', $salutation);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':surname', $lastname);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':address', $address);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':loctation', $location);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':country', $country);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':remoteAddress', $ip);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':createdon', $created_on);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $conn = null;
    echo $e;
}
```

That was just a test and it seems to work. Now I would like to do everything dynamically.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/srv/www/micro/weltwochen.lasttry.db.json'));
```

With `$json` I get a JSON object. I am not interested in values of the JSON file but I would like to use the attributes of it for the columns of my MySQL table.

All JSON attributes are called the same as the string of `$_POST[]`.

**EXAMPLE**

If JSON has an attribute called `first_name`, then insert the value of `$_POST['first_name']`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the format of the JSON data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a query string for `prepare()`. Here is one way to do it using string manipulation. This method is viable if you control and trust the JSON file, but if the JSON file comes from an insecure source this code might be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) through the dynamic keys. I'd be *very* wary in that case.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/srv/www/micro/weltwochen.lasttry.db.json'), true);

$keys = array_keys($json);
$column_names = implode(", ", $keys);
$place_markers = implode(", ", array_map(function($column) {return ':'.$column;}, $keys));
$query = "INSERT INTO t_weltwoche_address_infos2018_test (" . $column_names . ") VALUES (" . $place_markers . ")";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $_POST[$key]);
}
```

Comment: JSON file is fully trusted. Amazing how you did that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use pass `true` as the optional `$assoc` parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)...

```
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents('/srv/www/micro/weltwochen.lasttry.db.json'),
                     true );
```

then

`$json` variable already contains data in the format you ask.

Ex. you may access `$json['first_name']`

Of course the above is valid provided that the JSON encoded data parsed has the following format (a single object of key-value pairs):

```
{ 
    "first_name":    "Reza",
    "surname":       "Saadati",
    "address"....

}
```

If it's not the case then the decoded array `$json` needs to be "mangled". How to do that depends on the format of the source JSON; you may include that in your answer in case.