# Insert rows into database table from 2d json data using a PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, insert

I do a lot of data transfers from sites to sites mainly DB data..  Latest was a simple pdo DB query, fetchall, then Jason encode the data, send to remote site and populate database with data, same database structure.

I thought i could simplify this, I use last record as staring point.  I send request to source server with a start value of last ID in receiving db then run this on source.

```
if ($_GET['start']){
    $startId = $_GET['start'];
    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` where `id` > $startId  LIMIT 0,5 ");
    $r= $q->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $out = json_encode($r);
    print $out;
}
```

this generates the jason data as expected, I take that on receiving side and convert to array, then use pdo to update, but after 24 hours of not inserting I give up!

Any thoughts where this is going wrong? or a better way to transfer data

code on receiving side

```
    $a = json_decode($html,true);
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    print '</pre>';
}


foreach ($a as $data){
    if(!$valc){
        $valc = '(';
        foreach($data as $val){
            $valc = $valc.'?,';
        }
        $valc = rtrim($valc, ",");
        $valc = $valc.")";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (".implode(', ', array_keys($data)).") VALUES ".$valc." ";
    print '<h4>'.$sql.'</h4>';
    $stmt = $dbo->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute($data);
```

everything looks correct yet no insert is happening.  I tried to first insert many rows with one insert but now to looping but still not working...

Tables are same structure on both side.

Comment: Always tag your questions with the appropriate language tag to ensure they get seen by the largest audience.

Comment: Your source server query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a prepared query instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: What's in `$a` and `$sql`?

Comment: Related: [Dynamic SQL Inserts for JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68687761/2943403) and [INSERT INTO dynamic columns from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49813216/2943403)

Comment: and [Insert multiple rows into database from json containing multidimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74425202/2943403)

Comment: and [Insert Into MySQL from Dynamic Array sent through Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31130555/2943403)

Comment: You are `SELECT`ing full rows of data, so you don't need to nominate the columns at all in your `INSERT` query and the table name is known in advance.  For that reason, those parts of your task can be hardcoded.  This question needs a [mcve] and Debugging Details.

Comment: While your implementation of re-using a prepared statement wasn't perfect, this is just a typo question where you have `$valc = $valc.'?,';` prepending the actual value to the placeholder.

Comment: Stack Overflow has many pages dedicated to the task of declaring a prepared statement, binding parameters, then making iterated trips to the database (as well as building a multirow insert query).  Some historical pages: [PHP PDO batch insert from multi dimensional array failing to insert into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19295239/2943403) and [php PDO insert batch multiple rows with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15069962/2943403) and [What is the best way to insert multiple rows in PHP PDO MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26456219/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nekkanti's answer will work but is inefficient. If all the `$data` have the same set of array keys, then you can move the prepare out of the loop and just do an execute in the loop:

```php
$a = json_decode($html, true);

$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($a[0]));
$values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($a[0]), '?')); // Prepare the placeholder values

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($a as $data) {
    $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
}
```

You could also do the entire insert in one query, although you may run into limits on the number of parameters in a prepared query:

```php
$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($a[0]));
$values = implode('), (', array_fill(0, count($a), implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($a[0]), '?'))));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($sql);

// flatten array
$data = array_merge(...array_map('array_values', $a));
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Comment: OK that I get, I assumed there may have been a way to insert all data with one execute as well, but I see this will be more efficient as well. Thank you again

Comment: @RadiumChris if your data was small enough that the statement could fit in the query length limit, you could build a massive `VALUES` clause to insert it all at once. I don't think you'd save that much by doing that though.

Comment: @RadiumChris please see my edit, I've added code that could do it all in one insert.

Comment: Some data sets will be very large, so the loop ok and actually quite efficient now.  I will update other transfers the  same, for my project the loop is quite acceptable.

Comment: @RadiumChris good to hear. I thought I'd add the single execute code just for future reference even if not applicable now.